# button hide /show GET date parameters

Tags: jquery

I have a website where I display 25 buttons in a gallery. I only want these buttons hidden. If the date passed in the URL is past 1,2,3 ... 25 days button visible.
For example, the URL passed is:  mayurl.com/?fd=8-9-2019    (M-D-Y)

```
Button 1 = visible
Button 2 = hidden and visible  8-10-2019
Button 3 = hidden and visible 8-11-2019
...
...
...
Button 25 = Hidden and visible 9-3-2019
```

Can this be done in jQuery? I'm totally new to this, please help.

Grateful thanks

Comment: This question could be clearer and should include actual code you have tried. https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: Unfortunately, I couldn't compile usable code because I couldn't find the right information on the Internet.

Comment: What do you mean with "Hidden **and** visible"?

Comment: Valahogy így gondolnám:
böngészőben megjelenő link:  mayurl.com/?fd=8-9-2019
 
   
Persze ez így biztos semmit nem csinál, hiszen nem értek hozzá.
Csak ide írtam amit gondoltam.

Comment: $.get("date", function()
    if date 8-9-2019 
    $("button1").hide();
    if date 8-9-2019 +1
    $("button1").show();

Comment: In fact, a drop of content would end. In a way that I would give the start date in the link and each day would see a button for a newer curriculum. If the date is the same as the date in the link, the first button is shown and the other buttons are not.

If the date on the link is the date +1 day, then the first and second buttons are shown and the others are not.

If the date in the link is +2 days then the first and second and third buttons are shown and the others are not.

And so up to 25.

Panels and buttons are made with WP + Divi.

Comment: Okay, I think I get what you mean. I will update my answer.

Comment: I have updated my answer. Is it what you were looking for?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the code below, date in url is "8-9-2019". Today, "8-20-2019", 11 days has past since "8-9-2019" so 11 buttons are shown. Tomorrow, "8-21-2019", 12 days will have past since "8-9-2019" so 12 buttons will be shown. Is this how you mean?

```js
// Define dateInUrl. It is hardcoded in this example. Change 'new Date("8-9-2019")' to 'getUrlParameter("fd")' when using the code on your real website
var dateInUrl = new Date("8-9-2019");
// Define hours,minutes,seconds and milliseconds in a day
var oneDay = 24*60*60*1000;
// Define today's date
var currentDate = new Date();
// Get number of days between date in URL and today's date from function diffDays
var nDays = diffDays(dateInUrl, currentDate);

// Loop through all buttons
$(':button').each(function () {
  // If the button's id is larger than the number of days between date in URL and today's date...
  if (this.id > nDays) {
    // ...hide it!
    $(this).hide();
  }
});

// Function for calculating days between two dates
function diffDays(d1, d2) {
  var ndays;
  var tv1 = d1.getTime();
  var tv2 = d2.getTime();

  ndays = (tv2 - tv1) / 1000 / 86400;
  ndays = Math.round(ndays - 0.5);
  return ndays;
}

// Function for getting parameter from URL
var getUrlParameter = function getUrlParameter(sParam) {
  var sPageURL = window.location.search.substring(1),
  sURLVariables = sPageURL.split('&'),
  sParameterName,
  i;

  for (i = 0; i < sURLVariables.length; i++) {
    sParameterName = sURLVariables[i].split('=');

    if (sParameterName[0] === sParam) {
      return sParameterName[1] === undefined ? true : decodeURIComponent(sParameterName[1]);
    }
  }
};
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div>
  Button 1:
  <button type="button" id="1">Button</button>
</div>
<div>
  Button 2:
  <button type="button" id="2">Button</button>
</div>
<div>
  Button 3:
  <button type="button" id="3">Button</button>
</div>
<div>
  Button 4:
  <button type="button" id="4">Button</button>
</div>
<div>
  Button 5:
  <button type="button" id="5">Button</button>
</div>
<div>
  Button 6:
  <button type="button" id="6">Button</button>
</div>
<div>
  Button 7:
  <button type="button" id="7">Button</button>
</div>
<div>
  Button 8:
  <button type="button" id="8">Button</button>
</div>
<div>
  Button 9:
  <button type="button" id="9">Button</button>
</div>
<div>
  Button 10:
  <button type="button" id="10">Button</button>
</div>
<div>
  Button 11:
  <button type="button" id="11">Button</button>
</div>
<div>
  Button 12:
  <button type="button" id="12">Button</button>
</div>
<div>
  Button 13:
  <button type="button" id="13">Button</button>
</div>
<div>
  Button 14:
  <button type="button" id="14">Button</button>
</div>
<div>
  Button 15:
  <button type="button" id="15">Button</button>
</div>
<div>
  Button 16:
  <button type="button" id="16">Button</button>
</div>
<div>
  Button 17:
  <button type="button" id="17">Button</button>
</div>
<div>
  Button 18:
  <button type="button" id="18">Button</button>
</div>
<div>
  Button 19:
  <button type="button" id="19">Button</button>
</div>
<div>
  Button 20:
  <button type="button" id="20">Button</button>
</div>
<div>
  Button 21:
  <button type="button" id="21">Button</button>
</div>
<div>
  Button 22:
  <button type="button" id="22">Button</button>
</div>
<div>
  Button 23:
  <button type="button" id="23">Button</button>
</div>
<div>
  Button 24:
  <button type="button" id="24">Button</button>
</div>
<div>
  Button 25:
  <button type="button" id="25">Button</button>
</div>
```

Comment: Yeah, I was just thinking about something like that, just the other way around. So if today on 20.08.2019 11 days have passed since 09.08.2019, the first 11 buttons are visible and the next 14 buttons are not yet visible.

Comment: Yes, it does exactly what I was thinking.
I have to figure out how to code get it into Wordpress and Divi.
Thank you very much for the solution and for the many help.